# How to set the overflow property dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, overflow

I'm trying to set the css `overflow` property to `scroll` dynamically when the mouse is hovered to an iframe. But it's not displaying the scroll bar when hovered.

I tested this in firefox version 5.0

Below is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sukumar/6ERtz/7/

Comment: Its working fine in FireFox 3.6.22

Comment: In IE8 it seems to display ok on hover, but it also displays the bar when not hovered...not that that's much help!

Comment: @dougajmcdonald  yeh..even i got puzzled with that..not sure whether it is bug in IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite display property for `IFRAME` element. Forcing IFRAME to be `display:block` solves the problem.

This is due to default `display` value for `IFRAME` in Firefox which is `inline`. Inline elements can't get scrollbars so your `IFRAME` is cropped.

Comment: Wow..it's working...just small question..why it is showing scroll bar in internet explorer even without hovering..

Comment: I think it's because of default scrolling settings in different browsers.  It will work as you like if you additionally change the `scrolling` attribute. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/avall/jyLnA/1/

Comment: I had checked in IE 8 and it's hiding scrollbar by default and not  even displaying scroll when hovered

Comment: IMHO the only way to deal with IE is to set `scrolling="yes"` or maybe wrap IFRAME with `<div style="overflow:hidden">` which will make the crop thing instead of `IFRAME`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/avall/WHDFb/  This should work everywhere - I made an example with `DIV` wrap which does the crop thing.